# Как сделать сортировку студентов по среднему баллу?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как написать функцию сортировки студентов по среднему баллу?

```
import random


class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, group, academic_performance):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group
        self.academic_performance = academic_performance

    def print_info(self):
        print("ФИ: {}\nГруппа: {}\nОценки: {}".format(
            self.name, self.group, self.academic_performance))
        print("-" * 30)


names = ['Гриша ', 'Петя', 'Федя', 'Олег', 'Максим', 'Артур', 'Миша', 'Вася']
surnames = ['Петров', 'Смирнов', 'Яковлев', 'Захаров', 'Фролов', 'Поляков', 'Крылов', 'Наумов']



def arithmetic_mean(students):
    for student in students:
        print(student.name)
        print(student.academic_performance)


def sorted_list(students):
   pass



def main():
    students = []
    for _ in range(10):
        students.append(Student(random.choice(names) + ' ' + random.choice(surnames), 
        random.randint(1, 8), [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(5)]))

    arithmetic_mean(students)
    sorted_list(students)


main()
```

Comment: приведите пример, который вы написали, а он не работает. И конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: В данный момент код рабочий, и выводит информацию о 10 сгенерированных рандомно студентах и их оценках, функция def sorted_list(students) сейчас пустая, мне нужна помощь в правильном написании этой функции чтобы она сортировала студентов по их среднему баллу.

Comment: Это понятно и так, по среднему баллу: "Сам не могу разобраться, уже по разному пробовал." - приведите свои попытки "по разному", укажите, что не работает в них.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно воспользоваться функцией `sorted()`, которая принимает в себя итерируемый  объект. Так же функция поддерживает дополнительные параметры. В данном случае нужен параметр `key`, на вход он ожидает функцию, с помощью которой должно быть выполнено сравнение.

```
import random

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, group, academic_performance, gpa):
        self.name = name
        self.group = group
        self.academic_performance = academic_performance
        self.gpa = gpa

    def print_info(self):
        print("ФИ: {}\nГруппа: {}\nОценки: {}\nСредний бал: {}".format(
            self.name, self.group, self.academic_performance, self.gpa))
        print("-" * 30)

names = ['Гриша ', 'Петя', 'Федя', 'Олег', 'Максим', 'Артур', 'Миша', 'Вася']
surnames = [
    'Петров', 'Смирнов', 'Яковлев', 'Захаров', 'Фролов', 'Поляков', 'Крылов',
    'Наумов'
]

def arithmetic_mean(students):
    for student in students:
        student.print_info()


def gpa_key(student):
    return student.gpa

def sorted_list(students):
    return sorted(students, key = gpa_key)

def main():
    students = []
    for _ in range(10):
        students.append( Student (random.choice(names) + ' ' + random.choice(surnames), random.randint(1, 8),[random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(5)], None))
    for student in students:
        student.gpa = sum(student.academic_performance) / len(student.academic_performance)

    students = sorted_list(students)
    arithmetic_mean(students)
    
main()
```

Comment: Точно, больше спасибо, теперь работает!)

Comment: Если тебе помог ответ, поставь галочку возле него